# занятость домена

Tags: домен

```
Domain Registration Date: 2014-06-28T10:25:37Z
Domain Expiration Date: 2015-06-27T23:59:59Z
Domain Last Updated Date: 2015-07-30T16:37:46Z
```

почему домен отображается как занятый?

Comment: может домен укажите?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что освобождается домен через 2 месяца после окончания срока регистрации

Comment: Это не полный и не точный ответ. Сроки, как правило, регулируются договором и вполне могут быть <> 2 мес.

Comment: конечно не полный, как и вопрос, в некоторы случаях срок резерва составляет 45 дней + 2 месяца, то есть в совокупности может доходить до 3,5 месяцев, плюс освобождение не всегда происходит точно, оно может затянутся на ещё 3-4 дня если они попадут на выходные , а если на праздники то может ещё дольше выйти

Answer (score 1):

Есть два понятия: *снятие* (или приостановление) делегирования и *освобождение* домена.

**Снятие делегирования** означает, что регистрар просто приостанавливает выдачу указателей на своих Name servers. При этом вы остаетесь полноценными владельцем. Кроме того, вы и сами можете снять (или приостановить делегирование), если, например, являетесь владельцем домена третьего и более нижних уровней.

А вот **освобождение** домена регистраром чаще всего означает, что вы не оплатили продление и, в соответствии с договором обслуживания, регистрар забирает домен и с этого момента он может быть зарегистрирован любым лицом.

И, наконец, ответ на вопрос:

В приведенной выше выписке, домену может быть приостановлено делегирование, но он все еще имеет реального владельца, который до определенной даты должен оплатить услугу по продлению обслуживания, дабы домен не освободили.